# Conditionnal Rsync based on mime-types

Tags: file, mime-types, rsync

I would like to know if there's a way of including only files matching a specific list of mime types with rsync.

It's quite easy to filter files based on their extension, but extensions could be missing or wrong.

I didn't find any native solution to do it, but maybe is there another tool or wrapper that offers this possibility. I thought it was quite a common need but I was unable to find threads or similar inquiries about this.

What do you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the rsync options closely, other than aging parameters, they are all geared to file location matching/control.

None relate to file content/type matching.

One reason might be because the database file used for the "file" command can be customized by end-users/admins (*I've done this to include a set of recognition strings for Prolog related files*).  That makes the filetype report a possibly moving-target and could be the reason why it was not implemented as a built-in.

One other reason is that filetype would take more compute time on a per file basis, even for those files that would not be copied.  That would be a significant hit on the rsync process time-to-completion for the rapid daily-delta backup jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage of the files which have no filetype suffix does not preclude the scenario, I would suggest you have a periodic job scan for such files without suffix and then another job to perform the rename to add a suffix.

If that can be automated, then you could consider including it as part of your backup process.  I myself would prefer to keep the two separate, for better situational control (manual review/exclusion of items in rename list).

I actually have a job to scan filenames for extraneous characters and provide me a report, so that I can "normalize" the names before performing my backups.  I do that also because some characters might interfere with the intended logic in scripts which expand variables into filenames for action.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, all files I need to sync are read-only so I can not perform any change to them.

Comment: Then that leaves only the option to present the system Admin with a request to facilitate your processes, and discuss the options and their pros/cons to identify the solution which is a best fit for your context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed whether the 'file' command correctly reports the type of file for all files that have no filetype suffix?

If so, you could then

- obtain the 'find' report for the directory trees of interest,
- parse to exclude any with a suffix,
- use the resulting list to generate a 'file' report,
- extract the subset that is of interest,
- then use the "rsync --files-from=FILELIST"

to specify which files need to be mirrored with rsync.